# What is the working of indexOf()?

Tags: java, string, indexof

I am studying strings and i came across indexOf() method. One of its overloaded method is

```
indexOf(int c)
```

so my question is that when we pass integer as argument then that integer is converted to character and that character is searched in the string and the index of that character is returned or that integer is treated as unicode value and conpared with unicode values of each character in the string?

Comment: When you have questions like this, you should take a look at the documentation: [click here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) you'll find the answer here

Comment: You study the String class without reading the documentation or the source code? How do you study it?

Comment: You pass a character instead of integer   for example  str.indexOf('a'); this 'a' is passed as in integer. int p='d';         System.out.println(p);  answer will be 100.

Answer (score 0):

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character. If a character with value ch occurs in the character sequence represented by this String object, then the index (in Unicode code units) of the first such occurrence is returned. For values of ch in the range from 0 to 0xFFFF (inclusive), this is the smallest value k such that:
>    this.charAt(k) == ch
>
> is true. For other values of ch, it is the smallest value k such that:
>   this.codePointAt(k) == ch
>
> is true. In either case, if no such character occurs in this string,
>   then -1 is returned. Parameters: ch a character (Unicode code point).
>   Returns: the index of the first occurrence of the character in the
>   character sequence represented by this object, or -1 if the character
>   does not occur.